# STM32G474 HAL Interrupt problem

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, uart, interrupts, hal-library

I've just started learning STM32. I want to make a simple code that uses UART in interrupt mode. Unfortunately I can't make it work.
I want an interruption occur when the microcontroller receives a character on UART3. I get the "While" text every 2,5s but nothing from the Interrupt handler nor from the Callback function.
I read a buch of example codes and I think it should work. 
Do you see the problem with my code?

```
#include "main.h"


UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart3;


void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void);


void USART3_IRQHandler(void)
{
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, "Interrupt\n", strlen("Interrupt\n"), 100);
  HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart3);

}

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, "CallBack\n", strlen("CallBack\n"), 100);
}

int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();

  while (1)
  {
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, "While\n", strlen("While\n"), 100);
      HAL_Delay(2500);
  }
}


void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};


  HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART2|RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART3;
  PeriphClkInit.Usart2ClockSelection = RCC_USART2CLKSOURCE_PCLK1;
  PeriphClkInit.Usart3ClockSelection = RCC_USART3CLKSOURCE_PCLK1;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}


static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{


  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart2.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetTxFifoThreshold(&huart2, UART_TXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetRxFifoThreshold(&huart2, UART_RXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_DisableFifoMode(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }


}


static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void)
{


  huart3.Instance = USART3;
  huart3.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart3.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart3.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart3.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart3.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart3.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart3.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart3.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart3.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;
  huart3.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetTxFifoThreshold(&huart3, UART_TXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetRxFifoThreshold(&huart3, UART_RXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_DisableFifoMode(&huart3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART3_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART3_IRQn);


}


static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{


  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

}


void Error_Handler(void)
{

}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT

void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{ 

}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're trying to achieve with this code, but if you're expecting to see a UART interrupt happen when you send data then you need to use `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT()` to send and not `HAL_UART_Transmit()`. Using `HAL_UART_Transmit()` inside the IRQ handler or the Callback is a bad idea. `HAL_UART_Transmit()` is a blocking function and you don't want to block inside an interrupt handler (the callback is called from the IRQ handler so that counts as the same thing).

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. 
I just want to make a code that returns the same characters that I send to the microcontroller from my PC. So I am expecting an interruption happen when the microcontroller receives a character. I put the transmit functions there so I can see which one of the fucntions occur properly. 
Unortunately the callback function is not called when I send a character to the microcontroller.

Comment: You need to setup the receive operation using a `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()` call to enable the receive interrupt. Then when the HAL code as received the number of bytes you specified in your `HAL_UART_Receive_IT()` call, it'll call the callback function to tell you that it's done.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Is it a proper way to put HAL_UART_Receive_IT() with 1 byte length into the Callback function If I want to receive messages with unkown length?

Comment: Yes - probably the only way to use the STM HAL functions to receive messages of unknown length is 1 byte at a time. For better efficiency you might consider using DMA to receive into a circular buffer in the background and then periodically checking to see how many bytes (if any) have been received since you last checked.